# Identification of tree with trilobate leaves

Tags: identification, trees

Can somebody help me identify this tree found in Sicily?

It is a fairly big tree (8-10 m) with a broad canopy and trilobate leaves. Fruits are also shown in the picture.

[image]

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it is a Bottle Tree, Genus - Brachychiton. Possibly populneus, australis or rupestris. There are some good photos here [BottleTree](http://www.delange.org/BottleTree/BottleTree.htm). More information can be found at [Davesgarden](http://davesgarden.com/guides/articles/view/2113#b) on some of the different varieties.

Comment: Thanks! It indeed appears to be Brachychiton populneus. Possibly subspecies _trilobus_ [see here](http://www.anbg.gov.au/gnp/interns-2002/brachychiton-populneus.html). It seems also that juvenile tree leaves shape can differ from the older tree one [see here](http://northernbeachesherbarium.com.au/gallery/v/Trees/Non-eucalypts_001/Brachychiton+populneus/Brachychiton+populneus+_10__001.JPG.html?g2_imageViewsIndex=1)